# How to set the different resolution on different iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an application using collection view. Here I am posting a screenshot and my code also. There is no error or warning in my application and I am using Xcode 6. I fixed the size of my viewController to iPhone 4-inch and run the application in iPhone 5. It is showing me perfect in iPhone 5 but when i select a simulator iPhone 6, the layout is look something oak ward. I post both screen shot. can anyone help me to solve this If some one run on iPhone 6 then I must show in perfect layout.

Screen shot of iPhone 5

[image]

Screen shot of iPhone 6

[image]

here is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    NSMutableArray *array;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:@"Apple"];
    [array addObject:@"Samsung"];
    [array addObject:@"Sony"];
    [array addObject:@"HTC"];
    [array addObject:@"Blackberry"];
    [array addObject:@"Oneplus"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark collection view methods


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [array count];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    label.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    //[cell.layer setCornerRadius:50.0f];

    return cell;

}
@end
```

Comment: Did you add Auto Layout constraints in your `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: RTFM. Search "Auto Layout" in Google or Apple Developer Portal.

Comment: If you know the perfect material regarding this then can you send a page link.

Comment: Stack Overflow is NOT a place to search for tutorial. Google is.

Comment: You are an excellent developer ratpor

Comment: so you know that this is tutorial. I don't know otherwise I don't be here.

Answer (score 0):

Please find helpful `screen shot`

I have added `constraint` as per your `requirement`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use auto layout or autoresizing to make compatible for every devices.
for auto layout go through this link.

http://captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/ios-7-tutorial-series-auto-layout-xcode-5

for autoresizing

[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interface-builder-xib-nib)

and if you add component pragmatically then check screen width for every device.

```
[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to images.xcassets, right clicking in the navigator area, add launchImage. Then select your project (or target), go to general-->App Icons and Launch images and set Launch Images Source as Launch Image and most importantly, set Launch Screen file blank.

The app would now work well in iphone 6 simulator too.[image]

PS: I also had the same problem. Solved it my self. See
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208804/iphone-app-not-showing-up-properly-on-iphone-6-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to images.xcassets, right clicking in the navigator area, select Appicon. Then check the ios 7 and later sizes. if iOS 8 and later sizes selected then remove that check box.
By doing that you will able to get your application run in all resolution iphone 4s,5 and 6.

See the screen shot.

[image]